# j query context menu for d3 rect

Tags: d3.js

Anyone know how to connect rectangle .on("contextmenu",  ??) with the jquery code to activate popup menu?

```
   $(function() {
     $.contextMenu({
         selector: '.rect',
         callback: function(key, options) {
             var m = "clicked: " + key;
             window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
         },
         items: {
             "edit": { name: "Edit", icon: "edit" },
             "cut": { name: "Cut", icon: "cut" },
             "copy": { name: "Copy", icon: "copy" },
             "paste": { name: "Paste", icon: "paste" },
             "delete": { name: "Delete", icon: "delete" },
             "sep1": "---------",
             "quit": { name: "Quit", icon: "quit" }
         }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `'.rect'` as your selector, make sure that you add a *class* of `rect` to your rect element when you create it in d3. If you just want to select `rect` elements regardless of their class name, then omit the period from the selector.

You can add a class of `'rect'` to a d3 element using `selection.attr('class', 'rect')` like this:

```
var theRect = svg.append('rect')
  .attr('class','rect')
  .attr('x', 60)
  .attr('y', 40)
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 60)
  .attr('fill', '#555');
```

Now your `contextMenu` should display as expected.

Here's a [**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/fitos/1/edit?js,output) showing a working example.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and working example.   Is it also possible to call this routine directly from the rect element using .on("contextmenu", ??)?